# XMLMapper.ReadValue return NPE with valid xml and empty values

Tags: java, data-binding, xmlmapper

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
</configurations>
```

When I read this xml using XMLMapper as below:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
List<Map<String, Object>> entries = xmlMapper.readValue(new File(xmlFileName), List.class);
```

I get null pointer exception with the following call stack:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:162)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:227)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:204)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2052)
>   ....
>   ....

Even when XML does not have values in between tags, it is still valid,  so I think the function should return empty list not NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is a bug in the implementation and for time being I handled the exception safely to solve this problem.